# Run a JHipster application on AWS EC2

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, jhipster

I have tried to run a JHipster application by using the following command on AWS EC2 Windows Server

```
java -jar jhipster-app.war
```

It is working fine on http://localhost:9090, but it is not accessible from the public IP

I have the security group rules defined like the image below

[image]

Comment: If you are trying to access this via the internet, is the instance within a public subnet? That is, does the route table the subnet is using provide a route to an internet gateway within your VPC?

Comment: It is the default VPC, I have n't created any new or edit the default VPC. The RDP protocol is working fine . Only the Application running on 9090 is not accessible.